# Add new column by comparing values of an existing column in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model that has a column `its_holiday` that is a `boolean` field in database. Now I want to add another column `its_not_a_holiday` that has a value opposite to that of the `its_holiday` column. How can I add this new column to the existing table and populate it with the values opposite to that of `its_holiday` column?

Comment: why do you want to do that? 
use the negate value of `its_holiday` instead of new column.

Comment: In all honesty I do not know why but it is a requirement which I do not know how to solve.

Comment: as I said, by using same field `its_holiday` it could be solvable.

Comment: I already used the same field and solved but this solution was rejected and I was told to do as I have asked in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your boss insists on having an `its_not_holiday` boolean (although other answers and comments have pointed out, you don't actually need to do that) you can do a migration as follows...

Create a migration

```
rails g migration AddItsNotAHolidayToMyModel its_not_a_holiday:boolean
```

Edit the migration as follows

```
class AddItsNotAHolidayToMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1] # or whatever version you have
  def up
    add_column :my_model, :its_not_a_holiday, :boolean, default: false
    MyModel.where(its_holiday: [false, nil]).update_all(its_not_a_holiday: true)
  end
  def down
    remove_column :my_model, :its_not_a_holiday
  end
end
```

You may want to modify the model to ensure the boolean is always set correctly when you save a record

```
class MyModel
  before_save :update_its_not_a_holiday

  private

  def update_its_not_a_holiday
    self.its_not_a_holiday = !its_holiday
  end
end
```

Comment: Like the way you explained the answer +1. Definitely going to up-vote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Nithin you can use negate value of its_holiday instead of new column. To follow good practice you should use the negate value. But if you still want to do that you can do it like this for existing records.

```
class AddItsNotAHolidayToModelName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :model_name, :its_not_a_holiday, :boolean
    ModelName.find_each do |model_name|
      model_name.its_not_a_holiday = !model_name.its_holiday
      model_name.save
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :model_name, :its_not_a_holiday
  end
end
```

and for new records

```
class ModelName
  before_save :update_its_not_a_holiday

  private

  def add_its_not_a_holiday
    self.its_not_a_holiday = !its_a_holiday
  end
end
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom method in your model file like this;

```rb
def its_not_a_holiday
  !its_holiday
end
```